# Read map key from stdin

Tags: dictionary, go, stdin

I have a map from strings to ints, I want to select a value by reading the key from stdin. Simple enough, you may say:

```
  package main
  import (
           "os"
           "bufio"
           "fmt"
  )
 
 func main() {
         m := map[string]int {
                 "Hello": 1,
                 "Map": 2,
         }
 
         reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
         text, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
 
         if err != nil {
                 fmt.Println("Error", err)
                 return
         }
 
         fmt.Println(m[text])
 }
```

When writing "Hello" to the console this prints out 0, not 1.

Comment: Have you checked what's exactly inside `text`? Please show the very output of `fmt.Printf("% x\n", text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were to guess, using `reader.ReadString` appends user input with a `\n`. So the `text` field ends up being `Hello\n`

Using `budio.NewScanner()` fixes this problem:

```golang
func main() {
    m := map[string]int{
        "Hello": 1,
        "Map":   2,
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Scan()
    text := scanner.Text()

    fmt.Println(m[text])
}
```

Output:

```sh
$ go run main.go
Hello
1
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

*ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and **including the delimiter**.*

If you slice your string and remove the last character it should work:

```golang
fmt.Println(m[text[:len(text)-1]])
```

Comment: did you mean strings.TrimSpace ?

Comment: No, I meant removing the last character from the text. That delimiter can be anything.